# How to set scroll on horizontal overflow but show scroll bar only on part of the box

Tags: html, css

I have the table with two sticky columns as shown on image. The stickyness is achieved with css styles applied to columns like so:

```
position: sticky !important;
left: 0;
z-index: 1;
background-color: white;
```

This is the result:
[image]

Now I can't figure out how to make the scrollbar smaller, so that it doesn't cover sticky columns, like below. That would make the UI better. How can I do it? Preferrably with css only, without the need to create two seperate divs/tables.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to solve the above stated problem.

Try these links[Link1](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/css/change+height+of+scrollbar+css),[Link2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scrollbar-width).
I was able to make adjustments in my scrollbar using these.

Comment: Great thank you, indeed, you just have to set margin left on track with scrollbar rules. Problem solved, thanks!

Comment: It's a non-standard browser feature though. And it's not supported in firefox. I will have to find another solution

Comment: Plus you can set margin on track but you cannot offset buttons so that they match new position of track from what I can tell.